# Kibana Elastic String to Date

Tags: date, elasticsearch, formatting, kibana

I'm trying to convert string to date, after much research 90% of the solutions point to this:

```java
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(doc['LAST_ORDER'].value).getTime();
```

But getting this error:

```
Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default.
```

[image]

PS: I would like to do this through Kibana dashboard instead of requests, still learning the basis.

Comment: Hey man, could you share the mapping of the index ? more specifically do you have a `keyword` type fields on the `LAST_ORDER` field? If so, use it. eg: 
`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(doc['LAST_ORDER.keyword'].value).getTime();
`

Comment: BUT, my advice for the future. Make sure your types are properly indexed at ingestion time. I'll help you down the line in so many ways